# Musical difference between "Chicago blues" and "Detroit blues"

Tags: genre, blues

When hearing a song for the first time, how can I tell whether it is Chicago blues or Detroit blues?

[Chicago blues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_blues) and [Detroit blues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detroit_blues) each have their own article on Wikipedia, the latter saying that they are "very similar in style". What is the subtle difference? Or is there no difference at all, musically?

Answer (score 6):

They're really just more to tell where a blues performer is from rather then describe the music as Chicago blues is blues from Chicago and Detroit blues is from Detroit.

Just in general in music there will be slightly different sounds to the same genre as people in the same scene will play together and have just a slightly different take on similar material. In this case it was deemed a separate genre, but stylistically there's really not much difference.